# Unable to compile python for android kivy distribution with pyserial

Tags: android, kivy, pyserial

I am unable to compile a distribution for android when i include pyserial in the python for android build requirements.
I am using the ubuntu kivy vm supplied from the kivy website.

After running the following command:

> ./distribute.sh -m "pil kivy pyjnius pyserial"

It compiles all the packages except the last one (pyserial) and I get this error:

> Installing collected packages: pyserial   Running setup.py install for
>   pyserial
>       changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/miniterm.py from 664 to 775
>
> ```
> changing mode of /tmp/tmp0r9vlU/bin/miniterm.py to 775 Successfully installed pyserial Cleaning up... Exception: Traceback
> ```
>
> (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/kivy/android/python-for-android/build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/home/kivy/android/python-for-android/build/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 311, in run
>       os.path.join(options.target_dir, item)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 291, in move
>       raise Error, "Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst Error: Destination path
>   '/home/kivy/android/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg-info/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg-info'
>   already exists
>
> Storing debug log for failure in /home/kivy/.pip/pip.log

Any help solving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this after a bit of checking the error log.

I will list it here in case someone has the same problem.

The following line:

> Error: Destination path
>   '/home/kivy/android/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg-info/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg-info'
>   already exists

indicates that the directory mentioned should be deleted, but this does not not help. Running the build script after deleting it generates the same error.

The solution was to also delete the directory named "serial" which can also be found in the "site-packages" directory.